# Would List be garbage collected if only iterator exists

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have method that creates and returns me List of users:

```
private List<User> createUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    //fill list
    return users;
}
```

After I get this list only thing I do is getting iterator and iterating thru it. So i am thinking about returning just iterator not whole list:

```
private Iterator<User> getUsersIterator() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    //fill list
    return users.iterator();
}
```

But I am not sure if that list would still be alive. Does existing of iterator avoid garbage collecting?

Comment: Yes it does, because the iterator is either an inner-class of the list, or embeds a reference to it.

Comment: Don't return an `Iterator`: you'd only be able to use it once; you can't iterate it with an enhanced for loop; and you can't do useful things like querying its size, should you need to in the future. I'd keep returning a `List`; but consider returning an unmodifiable view, perhaps: `return Collections.unmodifiableList(users);`. (There is an element of "YAGNI" in my suggestions; but `Iterator` isn't really a useful return type, other than to implement the `Iterable` interface).

Comment: The garbage collector exists so that you do not need to think about it. Why do so many people hearing about the garbage collector the first time assume that its purpose was to automate the creation of errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the existence of an iterator avoid garbage collection of a collection?

Yes.  A iterator must include a reference back to the collection.  This is needed for any normal implementation of the `next()` and `hasNext()` methods<sup>1</sup>.

So if the iterator is reachable, so is the collection.

This could also work against you.  For example, an unwanted reference to an iterator stashed in a static variable could cause a memory leak involving the entire collection.

---

<sup>1 - Hypothetically, an iterator implementation could use a soft or weak reference, but the consequence could be that an iteration "breaks" due to the collection being garbage collected.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Iterators require a reference to their backing collection in order to retrieve its elements, and hence a reference to it would prevent its collection from being garbage collected.

In the case of `ArrayList` for instance it is implemented as an inner class which keeps a reference to its enclosing class.